# Kill application which has been catched OutOfMemoryError

Tags: java, weblogic, ear, sunos

I have weblogic in Solaris 10 environment. My application had been caught OutOfMemoryError.

My question about killing bad build of application from shell script, not about tuning java or my code.

With Linux/BSD and Windows I can do pgrep for my particular application and do `kill -SIGTERM` and then `kill -SIGKILL` it. 
But on SunOS I can't pgrep them (ps(1) returns only first 80 symbols).

Does anybody know how to do it without drinking cup or too of coffee between redeploy?

Comment: ps -ef | grep java to see the application's pid then kill -9 <pid>

Comment: Talking about application - do you want to kill the application that has been deployed in weblogic or the entire server?

Comment: i mean application server, try ps -ef | grep java and u'll spot weblogic's process

Comment: I need to kill only particular instance, not entire server.

Comment: pgrep and pkill first appeared in Solaris and were later implemented in other OSes including Gnu/Linux. Can you clarify what precise version of Solaris you are using `cat /etc/release` that is missing pgrep ? I strongly doubt you are using SunOS 5.1 (Solaris 2.1).

Comment: pgrep is on place, but command lines are too long for it.  Server release is Solaris 10 10/09

Comment: That should be SunOS 5.10, not 5.1 which was released in 1993 or so. Should you want more than 80 characters in ps output, you can use "/usr/ucb/ps -alxww".

Comment: Wow!!! It is exactly what I want!

Comment: Okay, then I'll re post my comment as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should you want more than 80 characters from ps output, you can use `/usr/ucb/ps -alxww`

Answer (score 1):

use the JVM parameter `-XXexitOnOutOfMemory`  in case of a JRockit VM or use `-XX:OnOutOfMemoryError="kill -9 %p"` in case of a Sun JVM. This needs to be added to the start JVM args of the weblogic container.

Also see the Metalink note 1074735.1 for a listing on all of the nonstandard JVM options of JRockit JVM

Comment: It is not exactly what I want, but I can use it. Thanks a lot